# как правильно дописать запрос поиск доступных номеров между датами sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно чтобы искал доступные свободные номера между датами, Вот запрос  если в диапазоне номера свободны(пустые) то он покажет иначе он совсем не выводит(допустим существует одна запись @startDate = 25/08/2017 и @endDate = 27/08/2017 диапазон поиска с 1 числа до конца месяца то возвращает ничего, помогите новичку )

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search2]
 @start datetime,
 @end datetime
AS
BEGIN
select r.number,r.mesta, b.start_date,b.end_date  
from tbl_Rooms r 
join Booking b on b.room_id = r.id 
where r.id not in
    (select r.id from Booking b 
    where (@start between b.start_date and b.end_date or 
    @end between b.start_date and b.end_date)) 
END
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Comment: А что такое "свободный номер". я вижу запрос достает из одной таблицы id которых нет в другой за указанный диапазон. Причем с неправильным условием выбора, Если start_date будет меньше 25/08/2017 а enddate больше 27/08/2017 диапазоны вроде как пересекаются, однако под ваше условие они не попадают, верно ли это ?

Comment: Если начало и конец периода, скажем, 01.01 и 10.01  - Вам нужны номера, которые пустуют все 10 дней или те, которые пустуют хотя бы один день в этом периоде?

Comment: все номера которые пустые

Comment: @Zufir нужны все не забронированные номера исключая забронированные , благодарю за внимание!

Comment: может вам нужно условие вроде `@start <= b.end_date and 
    @end >= b.start_date` ? по крайней мере так вы получите пересечение хоть в один день. Правда еще не ясно зачем вы подклеиваете booing в основной части запроса, за счет него вы никогда не получите ни одного номера который ни разу не бронировался и получите номера, которые когда либо бронировались столько раз, сколько раз они были в брони

Comment: начинаю задумываться, попробую и так

Comment: @U.Bahti уточните пожалуйста. Если в запрашиваемом периоде 10 дней, а номер занят только 1 день из периода, то мы его в результате исключаем?

Comment: не совсем @VitalyKolyada исключая  тот день который забронирован в диапазоне  а остальные свободные если попадают в диапазон выводить

Answer (score 1):

Вариант выводящий все даты на которые номер свободен. В приведенном варианте используется генерация необходимых дат на лету c помощью `CTE`. Возможно в вашем случае лучше хранить возможные даты в отдельной таблице.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search2]
    @start datetime,
    @end datetime
  AS
BEGIN;
    WITH d1(n) AS (
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                  ),
         d2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM d1 CROSS JOIN d1 AS a),
         d3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM d2 CROSS JOIN d2 AS a),
         dates(free_date) AS (
            SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1)
                   free_date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) - 1, @start)
            FROM d3)
    SELECT
        r.number,
        r.mesta,
        d.free_date
    FROM dates AS d
    CROSS JOIN tbl_Rooms  AS r
    LEFT JOIN Booking AS b ON b.room_id = r.id
                          AND d.free_date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
    where b.id IS NULL;
END
```

---

Первая версия ответа. Вариант выводящий только номера свободные во всем диапазоне дат:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search2]
    @start datetime,
    @end datetime
  AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        r.number,
        r.mesta,
        @start,
        @end
    FROM tbl_RoomsAS  AS r
    LEFT JOIN Booking AS b ON b.room_id = r.id
                              AND @start <= b.end_date
                              AND @end >= b.start_date
    where b.id IS NULL
END
```

Comment: Спасибо @VitalyKolyada

Comment: @U.Bahti это решение выведет только номера свободные во все дни заданного периода.

Comment: да да так и получается схожий результирующий запрос `SELECT r.*
FROM tbl_Rooms r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Booking b
    WHERE b.room_id = r.id 
    AND 
    (
         '01/08/2017' BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date OR
         '30/08/2017' BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date OR 
         ('01/08/2017' <= b.start_date AND '30/08/2017' >= b.end_date
    )
))`

Comment: @U.Bahti какого вида выходной набор вы хотите видеть? Думаю вариант со столбцами `start_date` и `end_date` не лучшее решение. Я бы выводил набор с одним полем `date`. Скорее всего это для конечного приложения будет удобнее.

Comment: а нужны результаты всех свободных номеров исключая те что забронированы в заданном периоде.

Comment: только данные о номере

Comment: @U.Bahti это понятно. Имею ввиду, что на каждую свободную дату будет своя отдельная запись в выходном наборе, при условии что он в эту дату свободен.

Comment: тоже вариант попробую и так сделать

Comment: не подскажете  link на эту тему

Comment: Можно попробовать создавать на лету таблицу с необходимым числом дат на лету и джойнить к ней ваши таблицы.

Comment: извиняюсь я притупил что то, заменить на `date` и ваша процедура

Comment: @U.Bahti обновил ответ с учетом вывода дат. Кстати, на всякий случай стоит проверить какой тип данных у ваших полей `start_date` `end_date`. Если `datetime` будет не лишним убедиться, что время не имеет в них значения.